# $ (X_n,Y_n)\rightarrow^{P} (X,Y)$ iff $ X_n\rightarrow^{P} X \>and \> Y_n\rightarrow^{P} Y$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Recall a random vector $(X_n,Y_n)$ converges in probability to a limit vector $(X,Y)$ if
$$ d((X_n,Y_n)(X,Y))\rightarrow^{P} 0$$
where $d$ is the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R^2}$
Prove $$ (X_n,Y_n)\rightarrow^{P} (X,Y)$$
iff
$$ X_n\rightarrow^{P} X  \>and \> Y_n\rightarrow^{P} Y$$

## Proof

Assume$ (X_n,Y_n)\rightarrow^{P} (X,Y)$
Observe $P[|X_n-X|^{2} >\epsilon^2]\leq P[|X_n-X|^{2}+|Y_n-Y|^{2}> \epsilon^{2}]=P[d((X_n,Y_n)(X,Y))> \epsilon]\rightarrow 0$
So $ X_n\rightarrow^{P} X  \>and \> Y_n\rightarrow^{P} Y$

I need help with the other direction

Comment: Your proof shows the opposite of what you claim.  You assume $P[d((X_n,Y_n),(X,Y)) > \epsilon] \to 0$, i.e. that the *pair* converges in probability, and used that to prove that $X_n \to X$ in probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $X_n\xrightarrow{p} X$ and $Y_n\xrightarrow{p} Y$. Then

$$
\mathsf{P}\!\left(|X_n-X|^{2}+|Y_n-Y|^{2}> \epsilon^{2}\right)\le \mathsf{P}\!\left(|X_n-X|^2>\epsilon^2/2\right)+\mathsf{P}\!\left(|Y_n-Y|^2>\epsilon^2/2\right)\to 0.
$$